# Converting a hierarchicaly indexed Series to a sequence

Tags: python, list, pandas, sequence, hierarchical

Supose I have the following pandas Series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data= pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), index =[['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d'],[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3]])
```

Which ouputs:

```
a  1   -1.079086
   2    0.017873
   3    0.528414
b  1    1.462864
   2    0.314324
   3    1.194004
c  1   -0.723474
   2    2.431482
d  2    1.646265
   3    0.112295
dtype: float64
```

I want to obtain a sequence  which has as elements a list consisting of the second level indices. That is i want to obtain something of the form:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2], [2,3]]
```

What is the correct/efficient way to procceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [58]: data.reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(list).values.tolist()
Out[58]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
```